# How to run command prompt in Godaddy for installing porto theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

I am using Porto theme in localhost. I am using following commands to run Enable Theme for Currently Active store.

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now, we are going to live the website by using GoDaddy hosting.

[image]

In localhost, I am using the composer.

I have connected Putty with my IP successfully.

But, It is asking for Passphrase for key.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , This related connect SSH not related to magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following steps:

1. Open your putty then enter your website's IP address only.
2. Don't import any keys of SSH then click on Open.
3. Enter your Cpanel's username.
4. After insert your password.
5. Add your Path like `public_html/`.

Then run the following commands to upgrade.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect Your server via ssh

in linux you can connect via terminal using this command `ssh username@Ip(or domain)`

or if you are using windows you can connect via putty.

after connecting via ssh go to your magento root directory via `cd yourMagentoPath`

and fire those command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: @nukalasatish  put your username of ssh and then it ask for password

Comment: ok it means Cpanel username and password right

Comment: @nukalasatish tryit otherwise contact your server support for ssh username and password

Comment: I connected my site via Putty, How to go to my directory here?

Comment: @nukalasatish go to your root directory via `cd ` command

Comment: Please see once my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need the SSH access from server.

If you are using Shared server, then you have asked to Go-daddy that they are providing SSH access.

I think SSH access is not provided in shared server. So, Ask your vendor for SSH access.