# Magento 2 CSS/JS error in frontend and backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css, requirejs, 404

It first started after i set https://(My_Domain_Name).com into Configuration > Web > Base URLs & Base URLs (Secure) > Base URL for Static View Files & Secure Base URL for Static View Files (I'm not even sure if this is the cause). I tried several solutions including: (Solutions from similar problems in stackexchange)

1) Go to pub/static folder and remove everything, except .htaccess file. Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink and replace to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy. (It is already set to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy by default)

2) Using Putty to run below commands

```
    bin/magento setup:static-content:upgrade
    bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

3) Using Putty to run below commands

```
    php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
    php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
    php bin/magento cache:clean
```

4) The permission for /pub/ and /var/ folders is set to 0755 as per default.

I'm using Goddy Hosting > C-Panel > Magento 2.3.1 on Windows 10. First picture is from frontend and second picture is from backend.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have check css and js URLs are going 404. can you please execute this command again? `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Ok done. Command output: Execution time: 215.342

Comment: still facing same issue?

Comment: Yes, I've refreshed my website several times but the problem still exist.

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Magento version 2.3.1

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. +1 for appreciation :)

Comment: Would you kindly help me in this problem? (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276488/extension-installation-readiness-check-error-magento-2-3-1/276619?noredirect=1#comment395237_276619)

Comment: Sure, I will try my best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deployment script not working for you, then there is something missing in your `.htaccess` file.

Download same Magento version on your local system, and replace following .htaccess files

```
ROOT/.htaccess
ROOT/pub/.htaccess
ROOT/pub/static/.htaccess
```

Edit:
in `ROOT/.htaccess` and `ROOT/pub/.htaccess` file add following line on top of the file:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

Comment: After I download the same Magento version and replace the .htaccess files, both the frontend and backend have 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That's odd... let me check. meanwhile please revert your .htaccess files

Comment: edited my answer, check now

Comment: The 500 Inter Server Error still exist after adding the [SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto http HTTPS=on]. How do i revert back my .htaccess files? I replace them with the .htaccess file from my local system that i just downloaded. I think i made a big mistake for not copying the previous .htaccess file.

Comment: Yes, you should take a backup of old .htaccess files first. I also forgot to mention it in answer. try .htaccess files from this link I have got it from Magento 2.3.1 git code https://we.tl/t-91IDMk7EIJ

Comment: I've replaced the files you provided but the 505 Error still persist. The .htaccess files you provided is the same as the new .htaccess i just downloaded.

Comment: What will happen if I uninstall and reinstall my Magento 2.3.1 in my C-Panel? Will all the previous files/settings be overwritten? I only have several products in my store for practice because I only start to learn to use Magento last week

Comment: if you can reinstall Magento 2.3.1 then it would be better that you install it in different directory and them copy those .htaccess in your current website. the would be no need of uninstall current website

Comment: Currently there is only 3 options available in C-Panel > Magento. (1) Uninstall  (2) Install this application (3) Import existing application. I.m still pondering what to do next. By the way, thank you so much your time and sorry for the troubles

Comment: Why don't you do it on local server? xampp or Wampp or Lamp(for linux). Reinstall on local server and get .htaccess

Comment: So the solution right now is to get back the .htaccess files by reinstalling on Xampp and then hopefully fixing whatever is going on in the CSS/JS part?

Comment: if you get .htaccess from fresh installation, hopefully you CSS/JS issue would also resolve

Comment: I've checked in GitHub and the .htaccess files are the same as mine line by line  (from root_directory, pub, var) (except the extra line you asked me to add at the top of the line). I tried to remove the extra line and 505 Internal Server Error still exists.

Comment: I saw an article that suggest me to remove the .htaccess file from my root_directory and I didn't have 505 Internal Server Error after removing it. It says that "If it doesn't give 500 internal server error after removing the .htaccess file, then there must be some PHP version issue or any server configuration is missing." I would like to ask if there is any way to find out that missing configuration?

Comment: If you installed magento on server directly and it passed readiness check before, then there would be no mis-configuration.

Comment: Have you install new magento on xampp/wampp? It is better that you install fresh magento on local system and get .htaccess files from there

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I suffered from some health issue for the last month. After I get the .htaccess files from xampp, my magento stores work just fine. Thank you so much

Comment: That's great! You are welcome, please mark answer as correct if your issue resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

**I too got this error many times during fresh installation, hope this answer helps you.**

Try below sql commands in your db

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites';

INSERT INTO core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

and proceed below commands from your root directory

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```