# Extension Installation Readiness Check Error Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento-cron, php-7.2, readiness-check

There are several errors when I'm trying to install an extension (Slider Banner Module) for the first time. The picture below shows the error in the readiness check. I'm using GoDaddy > C-Panel > Magento 2.3.1 on Windows 10 with PHP version 7.2

[image: Readiness Check Failure]
1) For the Check Cron Scripts errors, I am able to solve it by manually change

`$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();`

`$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();`

to

`$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];`

`$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];`

I'm not sure if that is the correct way to fix it since there are no `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` files in `var`.

2) For the Dependency error, I have tried to remove `"require-dev":` in `composer.json` file but the error still persist.

3) For the PHP Settings Check error, I tried to change the memory limit in `.user.ini` and `.htaccess` from `memory_limit = 756M` to `memory_limit = 2G`, however, the C-Panel > PHP Selector > Options > Memory_limit still stays at 756M.
[image: PHP Memory Limit]

4) PHP Extensions Checks is as the picture below (Default Value)
[image: PHP Extensions]

Comment: Do you have shell access?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Putty and able to access my hosting server through it.

Comment: check if you can setup cron on it. use `crontab -e` to check if cronjobs are set

Comment: The output for crontab -e is: ```~ (empty)```  ```"/temp/crontab.XXXXX8NHQq" 0L, 0C 0,0-1 All```. There were no output for ```crontab -l```.I have set up cron in the Magento Admin > Stores > Configuration > System > Cron according to this link (https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-cronjob-schedule-tasks-magento-2.html).

Comment: Admin configuration is good, but you also need to set cronjobs on shell. Wait, let me add this one in anser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Access shell of your hosting
2. Go to your project directory
3. Execute this command inside your magento directory:
   `php bin/magento cron:install`
4. After installation of cron, set directory permissions
   by executing these commands
   `chmod -R 776 var/
   chmod -R 776 pub/
   chmod -R 776 generated/
   chmod -R 776 vendor/`
5. Check .htaccess of your magento directory and pub directory. See if it has `php_value memory_limit` value set, If it isn't then set it to `php_value memory_limit 2G` or if it is already there then make sure it is set to `1G` (Take backup of your .htaccess first :) )
6. Also check `max_execution_time` it should also set to `120` or more
7. If above steps didn't work for you then, set file permission to 777 from your godaddy cpanel on the directories that I have listed

Check readiness test after this.

Comment: Thank you Shoaib, after executing those commands, the 1) Check Cron Scripts problem is resolved (There are  ```.setup_cronjob_status``` and ```.update_cronjob_status``` files in ```var```. 2) PHP Settings Check and PHP Extensions Check are also resolved. Only the Check Component Dependency problem still persist (```We found conflicting component dependencies```).

Comment: That's good :). Please check point 5, I have updated my answer, check if it works for you

Comment: I tried changed the values as per recommended by you, however, I still receive the dependency error. Both the ```php_value memory_limit``` values in root and ```pub```are ```756M```. I'm only able to change it to ```1G``` by modifying ```memory_limit in .user.ini``` (Confirm after checking php_info()). Output for ```php_info()``` is ```memory_limit = 1G, max_execution_time = 18000``` (Local Value) , ```memory_limit = 756M, max_execution_time = 0``` (Master Value).

Comment: Sorry Nicholas, as recommended in the issue raised on github, you need to set `memory_limit` to 2G. Please see the link for clarification https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20684#issuecomment-484020760

Comment: I've changed the ```php_value memory_limit = 2G``` and ```max_execution_time = 120``` but the ```We found conflicting component dependencies``` error is still there. According to php_info(), the local value has changed accordingly but the Master Values are ```memory_limit = 756M, max_execution_time = 0``` (not sure if that's relevant).

Comment: Try to change both master and local value, may be readiness test is using global values. I am not sure but that could be a case, as this is the only solution that I have found

Comment: I had spent the last few days trying to change the master value for ```memory_limit``` and ```max_execution_time```, but all I had managed to change is the local value. Is there any non-conventional way to change it?

Comment: which hosting you are using?

Comment: I'm using Godaddy Hosting > C-panel.

Comment: 1) Look for ```.htaccess``` and change (twice): ```php_value memory_limit 2048M php_value, max_execution_time = 120```. 2) Look for ```.user.ini``` and change: ```memory_limit = 2048M, max_execution_time = 120```
Look for ```nginx.conf.sample``` and change (twice):
```fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2048M \n max_execution_time=120";``` This is one of the method I did but the master value remain the same.

Comment: check this one: https://codingcyber.org/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit-on-godaddy-hosting-882/ in your case may be you need to create php7.ini

Comment: ```memory_limit = 2048M```, ```max_execution_time = 120```, ```session.auto_start = off```, ```suhosin.session.cryptua = off```. These are all the values in my ```.user.ini``` file, is the value correct? In my ```php.ini``` file, the value inside it are ```error_reporting = E_ALL```, ```memory_limit = 2048M```, ```max_execution_time = 120```

Comment: ini values look fine, I don't know why you are getting this error :(

Comment: Mr. Shoaib sorry for troubling you. I have contacted my hosting provider and they increased the PHP Memory Limit to 2GB as per requested. However, the ```we found conflicting dependency``` problem still there. In this link (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html), it stated about modifying the ```composer.json```, do you know what needed to be changed?

Comment: Do I need to run ```composer install --no-dev``` or ```composer update --no-dev```? I have no prior knowledge on how to handle ```.json``` file so I'm reluctant to try it.

Comment: You don't need to edit `.json` file, I think you need to set file permission to 777 from your godaddy cpanel on the directories that I have listed in answer. After that delete the file `var/.update_cronjob_status` and `/var/.setup_cronjob_status` then check again

Comment: Thank you for your guidance Mr. Shoaib, it appears that the file permission needs to be 777 (at least for me) along with 2GB PHP memory limit in order for the Readiness Check to run smoothly. Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: Good to hear that :) +1 for appreciation

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue and fixed to set `cron` and `permission`

For your problem if you are setup `cron` correctly there must be two files generated in `var` directory called `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` if this two files are generated you are ready to run websetup wizard. `Also check the permission of both generated file is correct or not.`

**Refer bellow link for further information.**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you guide me through the process of fixing this problem? Do I run ```php bin/magento cron:install [--force]``` command in Putty?

Comment: Have you set cron?

Comment: Kirti, I have set up cron in the Magento Admin > Stores > Configuration > System > Cron according to this link (https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-cronjob-schedule-tasks-magento-2.html). However, there's still no ```.setup_cronjob_status``` and ```.update_cronjob_status``` files in ```var```.

Comment: Run cmd: crontab -e
And check cron has set or not ?

Comment: The output for ```crontab -e``` is: ```"/temp/crontab.XXXXX8NHQq" 0L, 0C    0,0-1   All```. The output for ```crontab -l``` is ```empty```

Comment: It Means your cron is not set.
you can run command: php bin/magento cron:install
to setup cron and check.